# Assigning numpad functions and macros with numlock off

Tags: windows, keyboard, macros, numlock, numpad

I'm looking into getting a 22-key numpad (such as the Leopold FC210TP) to use alongside a TenKeyless keyboard, and was wondering if it is possible to use the numpad as a macro keypad when numlock is off for stuff like photoshop shortcuts, whilst being able to enter numerical values with numlock on.

eg:

- Press 7 key --> **Numlock On**; outputs number (*7*), **Numlock Off**; outputs
  *ctrl+alt+J*
- Press 8 key --> **Numlock On**; outputs number (*8*), **Numlock Off**;
  outputs *alt+shift+ctrl+L*

And so on...

I've never done anything like this before, so I'm looking for help in how I could go about doing so, if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to comment, but I was looking for something just like this.

Unfortunately, like you I couldn't really find anything which does the job, so I wrote my own drag-and-drop software to allow me to assign automation/macros to my numeric keypad (numpad).

I found it super useful and am now making it available to anyone who wants it. It's only for Windows, but from your post tags, it looks like that's what you're on.

It's called Numpad Superpowers, and as the name suggests, the idea is that it gives your numpad computer-automating superpowers :)

Feel free to check it out - I hope it helps!

https://numpadsuperpowers.com/

Happy automating!

Comment: The link has changed into: https://hackaday.io/project/116883-numpad-superpowers